# bluebird promise in a simple for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise

I want to understand promises some more but i cant grasp the idea very well...
Let's say i have this example program:

```
var anArray = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
  var lastPage = i - 1;
  unirest.post('https://www.example.com/')
    .header('Accept', 'application/json')
    .send({
      "command": 'page[' + i + ']',
      "url": "[" + lastPage + "]"
    })
    .end(function (response) {
      // add result to anArray 
    });
}
//do stuff with anArray when all are done..
```

The callback of unirest will be called in a async mode so you dont know when it will get the results and when it will finish.

1. How can I log it at the end when its all done ?
2. Is there a way to break out of the loop with promises checking the response ?

Comment: Where does Bluebird enter the picture?

Comment: @DanielB bluebird as in the promises library..

Comment: Yes, that is clear, but you aren't using Bluebird in your code. Are you wondering how to use it, it are you missing code?

Comment: @DanielB yes I didnt use it because i dont know how to use it in this simple context because the other examples i really didnt get. But I do get allot of "problems" like this one and I know you can use the promises method to solve it

Comment: @MichaelAngelo : In the loop just create the request (promise for request) and push it to array. then using the `Bluebird` or some other promise library, pass that array to function which takes `array of promises` and return `single promise`. In `Q` (another promise library), `all()` is that function. Now you resolve this single promise using `then()`. I haven't tried bluebird yet so won't be able to code for that but core idea remains same.

Comment: @GauravGupta do you have an example how you do this with a Q library... to be honest i cant follow

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it with ES6 promises (which would also work with Bluebird):

```
var promises = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
  promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var lastPage = i - 1;
      unirest.post('https://www.example.com/')
        .header('Accept', 'application/json')
        .send({
          "command": 'page[' + i + ']',
          "url": "[" + lastPage + "]"
        })
        .end(function (response) {
          resolve(response);
        });
    }));
}
Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    // all promises are fulfilled here
    // results is an array of all the responses, in order
}, function(err) {
    // one or more promises rejected, err is the first rejection reason
});
```

FYI, this runs all 29 requests at the same time (they are all sent immediately and are all in-flight to the server at the same time).  I'm assuming that is what you wanted.

---

You could also use several of Bluebird's collection iteration functions like `Bluebird.map()` to directly iterate the array.

And, if you're going to use the `unirest` interface with promises, you probably want to figure out how to promisify the interface so you have a version of it with promises built-in so you can just use it that way rather than having to put a promise into it everytime you want to use it.  I don't know enough about how that interface works to suggest how to promisify it here so I just make your one set of commands work with a promise.

Comment: @MichaelAngelo - Did this answers solve your issue? If so, please mark an answer as the accepted answer by checking the green checkmark to the left of that answer to indicate to the community that your question has been answered and then both you and the person who provided the answer will earn some reputation points that can lead to more privileges here on StackOverflow.   If you didn't get your issue solved, then please explain where you are stuck.